# Virtual Hosts: Sites-available/myfilename.conf structure

Tags: apache-httpd

I had the url http://mydomain1 running locally on apache.
Now I want to make http://mydomain2 accessible as well.

I added the respective Tags in the myfilename.conf

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mydomain2       
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/myname/Documents/Workspace/mydomain2/
        <Directory /home/myname/Documents/Workspace/mydomain2/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
        ServerSignature On
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mydomain1       
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/myname/Documents/Workspace/mydomain1/
        <Directory /home/myname/Documents/Workspace/mydomain1/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
        ServerSignature On
</VirtualHost>
```

I restart apache.

Still, I can access nothing on http://mydomain2, browser rather redirects me to www.mydomain2.com.

Comment: Do you have an entry in `/etc/hosts` or a DNS record for mydomain2?

Comment: no, this might be the solution!